# Language switch for website in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

Im trying to make a language switch in my CakePHP website but I cant seem to pass the correct information to my functions.

in my website I have two buttons English and Dutch:

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('ENG'), array('controller' => 'Webpages', 'action' => 'checkLanguage', 'ENG'), array('class' => 'pure-button button-small')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Html->link(__('NL'), array('controller' => 'Webpages', 'action' => 'checkLanguage', 'NL'), array('class' => 'pure-button button-small')); ?>
```

These two buttons pass a string either 'ENG' or 'NL' to a function in my webpagesController.php, at this point the string should be in $selectlanguage which is given in the parameters.

```
public function checkLanguage($selectlanguage){
    $this -> loadModel('Language');

    //get information from $selectlanguage
    $selectedlanguage = $this -> Session -> read('thisSelectedLanguage');

    //set information for $selectedlanguage
    $this -> Session -> write('thisSelectedLanguage', $selectedlanguage);

    //set language ID   
    $this -> Language -> id = $languageID;

   //get language id
    $thisLanguage = $this -> Language -> find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Language.language_id' => $languageID,
            'Language.language_code' => $selectedlanguage
        )
    ));

    // expose data-record to the related view
    $this -> set('thisLanguage', $thisLanguage);


    $this -> redirect(array(
        'controller' => 'Webpages',
        'action' => 'homepage'
    ));

}
```

In this function I'm trying to match the right ID (Language.language_id) with the variable $selectlanguage which contains either 'ENG' or 'NL'.

'NL' and 'ENG' are the two ISO codes I store in my language table under (Language.language_code).

if I have the correct ID in a variable I need to be able to pass this on to the function that corresponds to the page.

homepage function in webpagesController.php:

```
public function homepage() {

        // load the website base-layout
        $this -> layout = 'homepagelayout';
        // load relevant models
        $this -> loadModel('Image');
        $this -> loadModel('Newstext');
        $this -> loadModel('Contenttext');        

        $activelanguage = 2;

        $mda = $this -> Contenttext -> find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Contentitem.contentitem_slug' => 'mda', 
                'Language.language_id' => $activelanguage
            )
        ));
        $this->set('mda', $mda);
}
```

after $activelanguage the '2' needs to be replaced with the variable containing the correct ID corresponding to the selected language.

Is someone able to help me? It seems I am close to the solution.

Comment: Aren't you mixing up standards?  I'd expect 2-characters throughout, ie 'EN' not 'ENG'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was, I was writing in the wrong function.

```
public function checkLanguage($selectlanguage){

//set session key
$this -> Session -> write('thisSelectedLanguage', $selectlanguage); 


    $this -> redirect(array(
        'controller' => 'Webpages',
        'action' => 'homepage'
    ));

}
```

This function above only has to set the session key and the rest of the information needs to be placed in the corresponding webpage function.

```
public function homepage() {

    // load the website base-layout
    $this -> layout = 'homepagelayout';
    // load relevant models
    $this -> loadModel('Image');
    $this -> loadModel('Newstext');
    $this -> loadModel('Contenttext');
    $this -> loadModel('Language');        

    //get ISO code 
    $selectedlanguage = $this -> Session -> read('thisSelectedLanguage');

    //get language id
    $thisLanguage = $this -> Language -> find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Language.language_code' => $selectedlanguage
        )
    ));

    // expose data-record to the related view
    $this -> set('thisLanguage', $thisLanguage);


    // set $activelanguage to current language.
    $activelanguage = $thisLanguage['Language']['language_id'];
    // send snippets to screen

    $mda = $this -> Contenttext -> find('first', array(
        'conditions' => array(
            'Contentitem.contentitem_slug' => 'mda', 
            'Language.language_id' => $activelanguage
        )
    ));
    $this->set('mda', $mda);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check **$languageID** is not defining. you have to replace your **$languageID** with **$selectlanguag**e or assign **$selectlanguage** to **$languageID**.

Comment: wouldn't that overwrite the string in $selectlanguage?

Comment: $languageID = $selectlanguage before set language ID

Comment: ok, I recieve no errors, but I also can't debug from this function because it has no view. How can I test this?

Comment: print $thisLanguage and check

Comment: Ok, I give it as a paramter to homepage() and debugged it there, it gives null.